# Find SUM of items quantities received by JOIN two tables and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

i want to find the sum of items quantities received by join two tables...

[image]

I have tried

```
select * from items join receive_items ri on items.id = ri.item_id group by ri.item_id


+----------------+----------+--------------+
|id |   Name     | quantity |  categories  | 
+----------------+----------+--------------+
| 1 | Soap       |   5      |  cleanness   |
| 2 | Tea Bags   |   5      |  sundries    |
| 3 | Powder Milk|   5      |  sundries    |
+----------------+----------+--------------+
```

as you can see from the above table it only returns only quantity one value from receive_items instead of sum of the quantity on each item while each item has more than one

Comment: This is a simple `join` and `group by`.  What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried 

    select * from items join receive_items ri on items.id = ri.item_id group by ri.item_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read more about query building [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/index.htm) 
In your case simplest query is: 
 `select items.id as id, items.name as name, sum(receive_items.quantity) as quantity, items.categories as categories from items left join receive_items on items.id = receive_items.item_id group by items.id;`

Comment: than you very much this one worked and I'll read more about query building.